# CMake post-build custom command on multiple targets?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm learning CMake through a C++ hobby project using Visual Studio 2017, and the way I have it set up, I have one folder for source code and one folder for test code. I build the source code as a static library, and build the test code as an executable (using Catch2). The problem I have now is that these are two separate targets, and whenever one or both of these targets are rebuilt I want to run the testing executable. Now I can find out how to run a post-build event using ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND, but that only works for a single target. Putting multiple targets after "TARGET" leads to only the last target being used (I tested this), and duplicating the custom command can lead to the tests being run twice, and also it seems like poor code style. Is there any way to do this elegantly? My CMake file looks like this:

```
# CMakeList.txt : Top-level CMake project file, do global configuration
# and include sub-projects here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("SheepyEngine")

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set (HEADER_FILES 3rdParty/CImg/CImg.h)

set (SOURCE_DIRECTORY Source)

set (TEST_DIRECTORY Test)

# Include sub-projects.
add_subdirectory ("Source")
add_subdirectory ("Test")

# Include libraries
include_directories (
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/3rdParty/CImg"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/3rdParty/Catch2/single_include"
)


add_library (SheepyEngine STATIC 
    "${SOURCE_DIRECTORY}/Game.cpp" 
    "${SOURCE_DIRECTORY}/Game.h" 
    "${SOURCE_DIRECTORY}/GameObject.h"
    ${HEADER_FILES})

target_include_directories(SheepyEngine PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/3rdParty/CImg/)

add_executable(SheepyEngineTest "${TEST_DIRECTORY}/test.cpp" "3rdParty/Catch2/single_include/catch.hpp")

target_include_directories(SheepyEngineTest PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/3rdParty/Catch2/)

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.

if(${RUN_TESTS})
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
        TARGET SheepyEngineTest SheepyEngine
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Build/Debug/SheepyEngineTest.exe
    )
endif()
```

Comment: Sounds like you just need to set up a dependency for your test code on the library..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SheepyTestProgram target needs to be dependent on SheepyEngine:

`target_link_libraries(SheepyEngineTest SheepyEngine)`

Then the target of `add_custom_command` will be just SheepyEngineTest (`add_custom_command` accepts only a single target).